# Five 3:1 rectangles tiling a square

Tags: mathematics, geometry, tiling

Can you fully tile a square with 5 rectangles such that:

- Every rectangle has 3:1 ratio, ie., their length is **triple** their width.
- No part of any rectangle is outside the square.
- No two rectangles overlap.

Note that rectangles can have different size.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008337/how-many-prime-rectangle-tilings-are-there) we know that all tilings of any rectangle by 5 rectangles – except one – may be built up by joining tilings by a smaller number of rectangles edge-to-edge. Without loss of generality let their aspect ratios be $a,b$, then if they are joined on the "1" ends the combined tiling has aspect ratio $a+b$. Note that once we have a ratio-$a$ rectangle we also have a ratio-$1/a$ one, so we need to take union with reciprocals of the aspect ratios found at each stage.

What we find from this recursive process is

> [it's not possible, and the closest you can get is an aspect ratio of $\frac{57}{56}$.](https://tio.run/##lZHBisMgEIbv8xRT9qJUGhJbWBZ6zXuYaFhhqzJjSku3z541aeg563H@//uUMd3zdwz6M9E0feyqkanqfKhcuGJ6RTBQvOBAps8@BkZ/SZEytusADWP76vjsKMf48@4kinbsM4B1AxpryfWC5RdgOeTySAH5MIZiEY9W1LK64RAJb@hL8JQAXOMZ50hpqbAVWtXyCdyU6ap7mH23QMIo7ORMrrcKrhVy6UtgvR1oFuC4HdAFwN8t7eatP23XH/@lnx8Dc25oWWL5BWcFn9alJ/IhC0Nymv4A)

Now

> to handle the last remaining case – the "prime" tiling in the MSE question – let the square have side 1 and the NW/SW/SE/NE rectangles have lengths $s_1a,s_2b,s_3c,s_4d$ and heights $t_1a,t_2b,t_3c,t_4d$ respectively, where $\{s_i,t_i\}=\{1,3\}$. Solving this linear system for each of the 16 possibilities yields no solution in 6 cases, a negative value for one of $a,b,c,d$ in 8 cases and a solution *which leaves the central rectangle a perfect square, not a $3:1$ rectangle* in the last 2.

In conclusion

> there is no solution!

Comment: This is excellent. Thank you!